# How to expose different path of an operation?

Tags: springdoc

I have a spring boot application which is located behind a reverse proxy. This proxy rewrites paths.
In my application I have a REST controller and document it with springdoc

```
@Operation(summary = "Expose some data", ...)
@RequestMapping(path = "/a", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public MyDto getA() {
```

The springdoc / OpenAPI generation leads to an operation reachable at `/a`
However the reverse proxy makes it available at `/b`

How can I tell springdoc that it should not use the introspected path from the `@RequestMapping` annotation but instead pass a path to any springdoc annotation?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you refer the document at https://springdoc.org/index.html#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy

Comment: No, my question is about the REST services, not the springdoc-openapi-ui. The UI works exactly as stated in the doc. However there is no documentation about how to specify a different path for the REST services.

Comment: `how to specify a different path for the REST services` can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I realized this now through implementing a OpenApiCustomiser. However this is quite cumbersome.
It would really be helpful if there is a direct framework support, e. g. through an attribute in one of the annotations of Springdoc.

Comment: Try raising an issue at https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it easier for developers with the same issue: In the following you can find one example on how to override the operation paths with an `OpenApiCustomizer`. It can be set on `OpenAPI` directly or it can be overriden per group. It is written in Kotlin, but Java should be almost the same.

```kotlin
@Bean
fun myGroup(): GroupedOpenApi {
    val servers = listOf(
        Server().url("https://my-server.de/test").description("Test Server")
    )
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
        .group("myGroup")
        .packagesToScan("de.xxx.test")
        .addOpenApiCustomizer { openAPI ->
            openAPI.apply {
                info.version("1.0.4")
                servers = servers
                removePathPrefixes(this, "/api/v1/test")
            }
        }
        .build()
}

private fun removePathPrefixes(openAPI: OpenAPI, pathPrefix: String) {
    val newPaths = openAPI.paths.mapKeys { it.key.substringAfter(pathPrefix) }
    openAPI.paths.clear()
    newPaths.forEach {
        openAPI.paths.addPathItem(it.key, it.value)
    }
}
```